# After using PHP's getopt(), how can I tell what arguments remain?

Tags: php, getopt

OK, So PHP has a built-in [getopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) function which returns information about what program options the user has provided.  Only, unless I'm missing something, it's completely borked!  From the manual:

> The parsing of options will end at the first non-option found, anything that follows is discarded.

So `getopt()` returns an array with the *valid and parsed* options only.  You can still see the entire original command-line by looking at `$argv`, which remains unmodified, but how do you tell *where* in that command-line `getopt()` stopped parsing arguments?  It is essential to know this if you want treat the remainder of a command-line as other stuff (like, e.g., file names).

Here's an example...

Suppose I want to set up a script to accept the following arguments:

```
Usage: test [OPTION]... [FILE]...

Options:
  -a  something
  -b  something
  -c  something
```

Then I might call `getopt()` like this:

```
$args = getopt( 'abc' );
```

And, if I ran the script like this:

```
$ ./test.php -a -bccc file1 file2 file3
```

I should expect to have the following array returned to me:

```
Array
(
    [a] =>
    [b] =>
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
        )
)
```

So the question is this:  How on Earth am I supposed to know that the three unparsed, non-option `FILE` arguments start at `$argv[ 3 ]`???

Comment: You could look into Console_GetOpt (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023095/phps-command-line-option-parsing-howto) but it requires PEAR.

Comment: You specified the file as last parameter so you could do `$argv[count($argv) - 1]`

Comment: @EaterOfCode: that's not sufficient.  You can specify any number of files, so you need to know how many unparsed non-option arguments there are at the end.

Comment: If you have no parameters requiring values or optional values, you can simply trim all `$argv` elements starting with a hyphen, leaving only non-option arguments: `preg_grep('/^-/', $argv, PREG_GREP_INVERT)`

Comment: Haha, after for 30 minutes to solve this problem I found my own, old comment above. ;) The solution is still value. Updated usage: `$argv = array_values(preg_grep('/^-/', $argv, PREG_GREP_INVERT));`

Comment: With PHP 7.1 and later, there's an optional third parameter &$optind that receives the index of the first argument that remains. I don't know how to solve this for PHP 7.0 and earlier versions. All of those have now reached end of life, so if you can, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with PHP 7.1, `getopt` supports an optional by-ref param, `&$optind`, that contains the index where argument parsing stopped. This is useful for mixing flags with positional arguments. E.g.:

```
user@host:~$ php -r '$i = 0; getopt("a:b:", [], $i); print_r(array_slice($argv, $i));' -- -a 1 -b 2 hello1 hello2
Array
(
    [0] => hello1
    [1] => hello2
)
```

Comment: I'm writing in 2021 that I'm still constrained to PHP 5.5 and I cannot use the third option to `getopt()`.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody said you have ot use getopt. You may do it in any way you like:

```
$arg_a = null; // -a=YOUR_OPTION_A_VALUE
$arg_b = null; // -b=YOUR_OPTION_A_VALUE
$arg_c = null; // -c=YOUR_OPTION_A_VALUE

$arg_file = null;  // -file=YOUR_OPTION_FILE_VALUE

foreach ( $argv as $arg )
{
    unset( $matches );

    if ( preg_match( '/^-a=(.*)$/', $arg, $matches ) )
    {
        $arg_a = $matches[1];
    }
    else if ( preg_match( '/^-b=(.*)$/', $arg, $matches ) )
    {
        $arg_b = $matches[1];
    }
    else if ( preg_match( '/^-c=(.*)$/', $arg, $matches ) )
    {
        $arg_c = $matches[1];
    }
    else if ( preg_match( '/^-file=(.*)$/', $arg, $matches ) )
    {
        $arg_file = $matches[1];
    }
    else
    {
        // all the unrecognized stuff
    }
}//foreach

if ( $arg_a === null )    { /* missing a - do sth here */ }
if ( $arg_b === null )    { /* missing b - do sth here */ }
if ( $arg_c === null )    { /* missing c - do sth here */ }
if ( $arg_file === null ) { /* missing file - do sth here */ }

echo "a=[$arg_a]\n";
echo "b=[$arg_b]\n";
echo "c=[$arg_c]\n";
echo "file=[$arg_file]\n";
```

I always do it like that and it works. Moreover I can do whatever I want with it.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd prefer to be able to use the built-in library, rather than hoick my own one around with me everywhere.  This seems like a serious flaw in the built-in library, to me.(Also, your example code won't handle, e.g., the `-bccc` command-line parameter in my example.  I'm sure there are more complete examples of command-line parsers for PHP out there, but that sort of defeats the point of this question!)

Comment: Simply use `strtok` and foreach the results will be better.

Comment: I've run into several situations where PHP's built in functions miss the mark a little and I've needed to build my own. I don't think this should be downvoted because it's creatively trying to solve the problem that PHP's built in function doesn't answer. It's not a perfect answer, but it's not a crappy one.

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly: it doesn't address the question, though--I already know I could roll my own!  My question was specifically about how I can use PHP's in-built getopt() for the purpose that it was intended.

Answer (score 2):

The following may be used to obtain any arguments following command line options.
It can be used before or after invoking PHP's `getopt()` with no change in outcome:

```
# $options = getopt('cdeh');

$argx = 0;

while (++$argx < $argc && preg_match('/^-/', $argv[$argx])); # (no loop body)

$arguments = array_slice($argv, $argx);
```

`$arguments` now contains any arguments following any leading options.
Alternatively, if you don't want the argument(s) in a separate array, then `$argx` is the index of the first actual argument: `$argv[$argx]`.

If there are no arguments, after any leading options, then:

- `$arguments` is an empty array `[]`, and
- `count($arguments) == 0`, and
- `$argx == $argc`.

Comment: This is a terrible answer! It skips over any command line arguments that begin with a `-` and assumes that the rest are non-option arguments! What if I run a command line this: `./example --name Bob -s 23`?  Here I may have *no* non-option arguments (if --name and -s both take an option argument), and your code would say that `["Bob", "-s", "23"]` were non-option arguments. The problem is that *until* you parse the options, you *can not tell* which arguments are non-option arguments.  PHP's `getopt()` would need to indicate which arguments are not part of an option, somehow. And it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GetOptionKit to get rid of the flag parsing.

http://github.com/c9s/GetOptionKit

GetOptionKit can be easily integrated into your command line script. It supports type constraint, value validation and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware that there are other libraries to do this.  I just wondered if there is a way to do it with PHP's native `getopt()` function.  Seems there isn't though.